# jqxgrid - how to remove the duplicated object values

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

I am usin jqxgrid to load my xml data to the grid, I want to find the duplicate values and remove from the first column of the grid:

I have find the duplicated values in my the alert, can any one help to how to remove that?

My HTML:

```
<div id="jqxgridAccountUpdates" class="jqx-hideborder jqGrid">                          </div>
```

XML:

```
<Accounts>
  <Account>
    <Company>Company 1</Company>
    <AccountNo>12345</AccountNo>
    <CCY>EUR</CCY>
    <Link>Link</Link>
    <StatusIMG>Approved</StatusIMG>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Company>Company 1</Company>
    <AccountNo>12345</AccountNo>
    <CCY>EUR</CCY>
    <Link>Link</Link>
    <StatusIMG>Approved</StatusIMG>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Company>Company 1</Company>
    <AccountNo>12345</AccountNo>
    <CCY>EUR</CCY>
    <Link>Link</Link>
    <StatusIMG>Approved</StatusIMG>
  </Account>
   <Account>
    <Company>Company 1</Company>
    <AccountNo>12345</AccountNo>
    <CCY>EUR</CCY>
    <Link>Link</Link>
    <StatusIMG>Approved</StatusIMG>
  </Account>
 <Account>
    <Company>Company 2</Company>
    <AccountNo>12345</AccountNo>
    <CCY>EUR</CCY>
    <Link>Link</Link>
    <StatusIMG>Approved</StatusIMG>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Company>Company 2</Company>
    <AccountNo>12345</AccountNo>
    <CCY>EUR</CCY>
    <Link>Link</Link>
    <StatusIMG>Approved</StatusIMG>
  </Account>
 <Account>
    <Company>Company 2</Company>
    <AccountNo>12345</AccountNo>
    <CCY>EUR</CCY>
    <Link>Link</Link>
    <StatusIMG>Approved</StatusIMG>
  </Account>
<Accounts>
```

JS ( in my ready function ):

```
var LatestAccounturl = "scripts/jqwidgets/sampledata/latestAccountUpdates.xml";
var LatestAccountsource =
{
    datatype: "xml",
    mtype: 'GET',
    datafields: [
        { name: 'Company', type: 'String'},
        { name: 'AccountNo', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'CCY', type: 'String' },
        { name: 'Link', type: 'bool' },
        { name: 'StatusIMG', type: 'String' }
    ],      
    root: "Accounts",
    record: "Account",
    url: LatestAccounturl
};

var LatestAccountdataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(LatestAccountsource, {
    loadComplete: function (data) { 
        var xml = $(data); 
        var compArray = []; 
        $('Accounts > Account > Company', xml).each(function() { 
            //alert($(this).text());
            var compTxt = $(this).text(); 
            if(compArray.indexOf(compTxt) > -1){ 
                alert("DUPLICATE: " + compTxt); 
            } else { 
                compArray.push(compTxt); 
            } 

        });
    },
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { alert("nooo"); }    
});
```

Comment: Got soln my own with ref of below fiddle :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PYdsm/